# How to display all components on a single page in angular 2 without bootstrapping them in appModule?

Tags: angular, components, angular2-routing

I want to display all of my angular 2 components on a single page so that i can see them all after I start 'npm'... How to do this with the help of router-outlet or parent-child relationship or anything like that??
I want to avoid bootstrapping all those components in AppModule.ts

Comment: welcome to SO - please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1) You can nest them. Give each component a selector and then nest the components in the App component like this:

```
<comp1></comp1>
<comp2></comp2>
<comp3></comp3>
```

2) You can set up multiple router outlets, either child outlets or secondary (also called auxiliary or named) outlets. This one requires a bit more setup ... so if you are wanting *quick* I'd go with option 1.